# discord.py - how do i mention a random member

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, slash, mention

how do i mention a random member in this code?

```
@tree.command(name = 'tinder')
async def tinder(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    users = interaction.guild.members
    await interaction.response.send_message(f'{interaction.user.mention} deu match com {random.choice(users)}  :flushed:')
```

"interaction.guild.members" only returns me the bot user

i'm using intents.member

```
intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.members = True
```

take a random member of the server the command was written on, not all servers

Answer (score 1):

Try using this code it should work fine.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

from random import choice

TOKEN = "TOKEN"

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="/", intents=intents)


@bot.command(name="randomMember")
async def command1(ctx: commands.Context):
    random_member = choice(ctx.guild.members)
    await ctx.send(f"Random member: {random_member.mention}")

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: I just noticed that this was 12 months ago...

Answer (score 0):

enable intents.members from [discord developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications) and then use *intents.member*.
This normally happens if *intent.members* is not enabled.

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "prefix", intents=intents)
```